# How can I count the number of all invoice's products?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a query with selects a specific invoice like this:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM invoices i
WHERE i.id = 15
```

Also I need to select all products that are belong to this invoice. I do that using this query:

```
SELECT i.*, p.*
FROM invoices i
LEFT JOIN pivot pi
  ON pi.invoice_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN products p
  ON pi.product_id = p.id
WHERE i.id = 15
```

Now I want to know, how can I use `count()` and calculate the number of products for the invoice?

---

I want a output like this:

```
+------+--------------+------+-----------+---------+
| i.id |   i.number   | p.id |  p.name   | count() |
+------+--------------+------+-----------+---------+
| 15   | 123456       | 3    | SX12      | 5       |
| 15   | 123456       | 17   | MGS2      | 5       |
| 15   | 123456       | 14   | BFE12-3   | 5       |
| 15   | 123456       | 32   | LG2-1     | 5       |
| 15   | 123456       | 6    | VBDS2     | 5       |
+------+--------------+------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: You should show what results you want.  Your question is rather unclear on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not clear what your desired outcome is. You could be asking to get every row from an invoice and include a column( which will be the same for every row) which is a count of all the DISTINCT products in the invoice.

Comment: add  also a coherent data sample and not only  the expected  result  ..

Comment: Just wanted note that depends on the use case here, it may be worth considering implementing a get_product_count_by_invoice_id() function

Comment: Why don't you just count the number of returned rows in your application?

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `GROUP BY`.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT i.id, i.number, p.id, p.name, IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) product_count
  FROM invoices i
  LEFT JOIN pivot pi ON pi.invoice_id = i.id
  LEFT JOIN products p ON p.id = pi.product_id
 WHERE (whatever you need)
 GROUP BY i.id, i.number, p.id, p.name
```

I guess from your use of `LEFT JOIN` operations that you want the invoice to appear in your result set even if it has no associated products. tHE `IFNULL()` function makes those rows contain `0` rather than null.

Comment: `GROUP BY... WHERE` Really? Come on sunshine.